# Display application icon on taskbar while splash screen is visible

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen, taskbar

i used splash screen (indicated inside manifest file) to show startup progress of my java (swing) application, but when the splash screen is displayed i want also to add task bar icon,  because if the splash screen lost focus it become invisible and it's impossible to show it again until the first window is displayed, so with task bar icon it will be possible to show it again to see current loading progress.

is it possible to show taskbar icon while splashScreen is visible before jvm starts or while program is loading and splashscreen is visible ? (like when eclipse starts it displays splash screen with task bar while loading application)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that is not possible using the default splash screen implementation.

You could however make you own splash screen using a JWindow and load the main application using a separate thread. There are a couple of examples available using google search like [this](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-splash-screen-with-progress-bar-4) and [this](http://javaknowledge.info/simple-splash-screen-with-progress-bar-in-java-swing/).